Reverse engineer Synapse Database(SQL datawarehouse) to ERD
I would like to create ERD for Azure Synapse Database(Dedicated SQL spool) db schemas. Suggest any tools and can we do reverse engineer to pull all the schemas and tables data.
I checked SSMS and Azure Data Studio and they don't have any option to create Database diagrams

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
